# Performance of Foreach and Template binding in knockout

Tags: performance, templates, knockout.js, foreach, nested

Have been looking into the performance issues with the foreach and template binding. In our single page app, we have nested foreach/templates. Below is the jsperf url, which gives the information on a plain array rendered without a foreach and the one with foreach; where the test with title "Expanded loop markup" is better than the "Nested foreach" binding.
 Also observed that the corrsponding "foreach via template" tests for nested and expanded are much more time consuming than the ones without foreach via template.

jsperf url:
http://jsperf.com/knockout-nested-foreach-vs-expanded-markup/2

Would appreciate your help on the performance with knockout 3.1.0

The performance issue is present with the knockout 3.2 version as well.

Want to know how to decrease the load time with nested foreach and/or template bindings.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @HansRoerdinkholder - i have added the question in the post.

Comment: When you load big tables of data, often nested foreach/template bindings are too slow. In this case, I usually create a custom binding to render the DOM, using low-level JavaScript: create a big HTML string, append it to a detached node and insert it into the DOM. I don't know of any way to make the bindings themselves faster.

Comment: In my knockout experience, Hans is absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

In line with what Hans outlined, if you are really looking to squeeze the most performance out of the client-side. A custom binding working directly with the collection, building HTML as a string and injecting it using something like `element.innerHTML`.

A simple [example](https://jsfiddle.net/pimbrouwers/pxjss6uw/3/) below:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.innerHtml = {
  init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    var lst = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());

    if (lst) {
      var html = '';

      for (var i = 0; i < lst.length; i++) {
        html += '<li>' + lst[i] + '</li>';
      }

      if (html)
        element.innerHTML = html;
    }
  }
};
    
var vm = function(){
  var self = this;
  self.lst = ko.observableArray();

  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var ary = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
    {
      ary.push(j)
    }

    self.lst.push({ num: i, numAry: ary});
  }

};

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ul data-bind="foreach: $data.lst">
  <li>  
    <span data-bind="text: num"></span>
    <ul data-bind="innerHtml: numAry"></ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```